# Is there any reason to throw an 'Exception' and catch it immediately?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

This code is from our project, production code:

```
if (changedToNull) {
    try {
        throw new Exception();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.debug("changedToNull", e);
    }
}
```

The developer does not work with us any more.

Why would someone throw an `Exception` and catch directly and log it?

Comment: It lets you get the stack trace.

Comment: If this is all there is to it, then it doesnt make any sense. If there were multiple Exception types were thrown as a result of complex business decisions and handled seperately, that might be acceptable. But overall controlling program flow with Exceptions is not considered a best practice.

Comment: To force the debugger to break or to check if enougth memory is for error-handling.

Comment: @resueman No need to throw for that.

Comment: Doesnt makes sense. I would just remove the try catch and just simply log in the meaningful message.

Comment: @resueman there are other ways to get a stacktace. The Exception is useless.

Comment: @f1sh useless would mean it did nothing.  In this case it's merely ugly and inefficient.

Comment: +1 for being curious.  Developers should have a reason for what they do when it looks weird.  Recognizing something as weird is a good trait for a developer to have, and asking about it is better than just ripping it out.  This is where comments *really* come in handy.  (though I'm not condoning the code being questioned)

Comment: It is very possible that the person debugged something and has written test code to gather information about a behavior and forgot the test code inside the code.

Comment: The linked question is asking about the same problem and the answer given is more comprehensive as it also shows multiple correct approaches to solve the task.

Comment: @Tunaki sorry but I disagree what you propose as duplicate is indeed the same question but it is totally a different use case which is not applicable here. Indeed it explains how to print the exception in **the standard error stream** which is not the case here (which is terrible practice btw), using `Thread.dumpStack()` is not applicable here and `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` doesn't bring anything to this context too.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The main purpose is to get a call stack when you enter in this `if` block for debugging purpose but it could be rewritten as next:

```
if (changedToNull) {
    log.debug("changedToNull", new Exception("changedToNull is true"));
}
```

Let's say that `changedToNull` should never be `true` and you want to get the call stack to understand how it occurred, you could proceed this way.

---

Creating a call stack is quite expensive so you should make sure that the `debug` level is enabled by checking the value of `isDebugEnabled()` too (assuming that you use `log4j`) as next:

```
if (changedToNull && log.isDebugEnabled()) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -5):

This looks like a useless bit of code to me. Some people have mentioned it would give you a stack trace but because it's just creating a new Exception the stack trace will unlikely give much useful information (unless in rare debugging cases).

I would rearrange the code to look like so and avoid even throwing the exception:

```
if (changedToNull) {
    log.debug("changedToNull");
}
```

If developers want to look into the code (while still in development) then they should ideally use an IDE built in debug tool.

A general rule of thumb is unless the code has a use in production then it might as well not be there and it's somewhat bad practice to keep it there. This excludes tests of course.

Comment: The stack trace will be as useful as any other. It'll show who called the code in question.